# Get available custom fields when creating new ticket in Request Tracker via REST

Tags: rt

I'm trying to get avaiable Custom Fields for a specific queue via `Request Tracker API` when I create a new ticket. For example when I set `Queue = 'X'` then I'd like to receive a `Custom Fields` key with values`A`, `B`, `C` that are available for that queue.

When I point my browser at `domain/REST/1.0/ticket/new` I receive the following response:

```
id: ticket/new
Queue: General
Requestor: xyz
Subject: 
Cc:
AdminCc:
Owner: 
Status: new
Priority: 
InitialPriority: 
FinalPriority: 
TimeEstimated: 0
Starts: 2018-12-17 15:40:43
Due: 
Attachment: 
Text:
```

As you can see i don't have any custom fields within the response as the queue points to `General` instead of `X`.

Can i modify the URL somehow to change `Queue: General` into `Queue: X` and receive all `custom fields` available for this queue?

Comment: According to the [RT-Wiki](https://rt-wiki.bestpractical.com/wiki/REST#Ticket_Create) you should send a HTTP `POST` request to this endpoint including the values you need in the ticket. Simply invoking the above mentioned URI will perform a HTTP `GET` request, which should be idempotent and safe. If the RT server, which I'm not familiar with, creates a new ticket by just invoking that URI with a `GET` request, it is probably already making something that it shouldn't do. Try using a browser plugin like `Postman` or `cURL` in your terminal instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the `content` variable of your new ticket request. For example:

1) Create a file `rt.file` with content:

```
id: ticket/new
Queue: support
Requestor: requestor@email
Priority: 4
CF-TicketCategory: Incident
Subject: Test REST
Text: Multi line
 test with
 special chars: žščřě
```

2) Post it with curl command: `url --data-urlencode content@rt.file --user username:password --url https://rtmachine.example.com/rest/REST/1.0/ticket/new`

See [RT-Wiki](https://rt-wiki.bestpractical.com/wiki/REST#Ticket_Create) for details.